# Написать параметрический декоратор cast(тип), который пытается преобразовать результат декорируемой функции к заданному типу. на питон

Tags: python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhQ13.png):почему код не работает всё вроде правильно

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код должен быть текстом прямо в вопросе, по картинкам тут не гадают

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, у вас функция `cast` ничего не возвращает. Строка `return invocation` находится внутри самой функции `invocation`, что очевидно не правильно.

Вероятно, у вас просто съехали отступы. Но наверняка сказать сложно, так как в вашем коде вы вообще делаете что-то непонятное.

Похоже, вам стоит ещё раз внимательно почитать, что такое декораторы, и как они работают. Потому что когда в вашем декораторе функция `wrapper` - это самая внутренняя функция, то складывается ощущение, что вы сами не понимаете, что хотите сделать. Так-то `wrapper` - это как раз обёртка, внутри неё должна быть какая-то ещё функция.

Comment: честно не понимаю что от меня хотят и как переводить одни данные в другие

Comment: И количество аргументов у декорируемой функции и её декоратора не совпадают